# Add page-break function to Vue-Multipane component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm having problems with [Vue-multipane](https://github.com/yansern/vue-multipane) component at my use-case and I don't find a solution.

I'm trying to disable the multipane once the screen size is smaller than 768px and display full-width rows instead of the columns. So my page is better usable on mobile.

Now I'm having two problems:

- Shrinked pane doesn't get maximized to 100% if screen size is below 768px (see screenshots below). So first reduce the width of the pane with the handle and then reduce the window width below the break point 786px to see the mentioned behavior.
- Handle isn't visible if reducing the screen size to 768 - 770px (close to the page-break). Page break not active but handle isn't visible. Not sure what's wrong - maybe that's easy to fix but I couldn't find a way yet.

[image: grafik] (missing handle)

Shrinked to 767px (should be maximized to 100%) - reduce pane than reduce width of window:
[image: grafik]

It should look like this (on page load it is displayed correctly):
[image: grafik]

Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/mh0wvLen/) or the code below.

But it's better to go to jsfiddle because it's easier to resize and test the mentioned behavior.

**What I've tried to solve the issues:**

- Add css styles `flex-grow: 1` and `width: 100%;` into the media query of the `left-pane` but that's not working.
- For the handle issue: I've changed the break point position a bit but the behaviour was still there.

**Note:** I've tested the code with Firefox.

```js
//console.log(Multipane, window)

const PageBreak = {
 data() {
   return {
     screenWidth: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    }
  },
 computed: {
   largeScreen () {
     return this.screenWidth > 768; // 10px for handle
    }
  },
  // bind event handlers to the `handleResize` method (defined below)
  mounted: function () {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },
  beforeDestroy: function () {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },

  methods: {
    // whenever the document is resized, re-set the 'fullHeight' variable
    handleResize (event) {
      this.screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  mixins: [ PageBreak ]
})
```

```css
.custom-resizer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.custom-resizer > .pane {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.custom-resizer > .multipane-resizer {
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.custom-resizer > .multipane-resizer:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 3px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -1.5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.custom-resizer > .multipane-resizer:hover:before {
  border-color: #999;
}

.left-pane {
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* stack panes if smaller than 768px*/
  .multipane.layout-v {
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
    display: block;
  }

  .left-pane {
    /*flex-grow: 1;*/
    /* how to maximize left-pane if it was shrinked before? */
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.3/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multipane@0.9.5/dist/vue-multipane.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <multipane class="custom-resizer" layout="vertical">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    <div>
      <h6 class="title is-6">Pane 1</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <multipane-resizer v-if="largeScreen"></multipane-resizer>
  <div class="pane" :style="{ flexGrow: 1 }">
    <div>
      <h6 class="title is-6">Pane 2</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<multipane-resizer></multipane-resizer>
  <div class="pane" :style="{ flexGrow: 1 }">
    <div>
      <h6 class="title is-6">Pane 3</h6>
    </div>
  </div>-->
</multipane>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a way to solve the issues. (The handle issue fix with the page break position is a bit hacky but works.)

Let me explain what I did:

- I added class `full_width` to the left pane if the screen is smaller than 768px to maximize the pane to `width: 100% !important` with this Vue code `:class="{full_width: !largeScreen}"`
- The handle was missing if I'm setting the page break position to 768px. I've reduced the position by 17px (looks like the padding 15px + 2px from border - but I couldn't change this with css) then it's working. So inside the computed property of `largeScreen` I'm returning it like this: `return this.screenWidth > (768 - 17);` (I've tested this by console logging the screen size.)

Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/mh0wvLen/4/).

I've you're having an explanation to the handle issue and why it's working if I'm changing the position by 17px - please let me know.

The solution is OK and seems to work for me. Maybe I'm filing an issue at Vue-multipane repo. for a feature request because it's probably easier if it's directly added in the Multipane component and it would be nice if passing the break-point with a property would work.